# How do you work around IndexedDb Transaction with async call

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker

I have a Worker which starts on a page opening. The worker opens a transaction, checks to see if a value is present on a record and if not needs to make a fetch call to get the value.

The issue I have is that I do this in a read/write transaction but the fetch is async which commits the transaction before the fetch is returned. If I could be guaranteed only a single page accessing the logic at the same time then I would just do it without a transaction, eg get the data, check it, if required get value and update. But I cant be guaranteed a single page.

So the question is how do I guaranteed that the second page doesn't start the process of getting a new value once the first page has started the process?

```
async function start(message) {
    var result = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let transaction = db.transaction(["Client"], "readwrite")
        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("Client");
        let request = objectStore.get(message.client_name);

        request.onerror = (event) => {
            reject(event);
        };

        request.onsuccess = async () => {
            try {
                let data = request.result
                if (!data) {
                    data = {
                        client_name: message.client_name,
                        sequence: 0,
                        api_base_url: message.api_base_url || 'https://api.local'
                    }
                }
                
                if (!data.last_access || dateDiff(Date.parse(data.last_access), new Date(), "m") > 20) {
                    let response = await fetch(data.api_base_url + '/v1/hello');
                    let responseData = await response.json();
                    data.id = responseData.id;
                    data.last_access = responseData.dt;
                }
                objectStore.put(data); // <-- Here is where it errors
                resolve(data.sequence);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `postMessage(true);` back to your webpage... store it in a higher scoped variable, like: `let higherVar; worker.onmessage = e=>{ higherVar = e.data; worker.terminate(); }`. Test `if(higherVar)` before you're `worker.postMessage`ing.

Comment: @StackSlave I'm not sure you got this question correctly. Their problem is that they open a DB transaction, and then, some of the times will wait until something async happens before being able to write through that transaction. The problem arises that multiple such scripts may be spawned in parallel (e.g because an other has been opened) and the ones coming later need a way to know the transaction is already being filled, instead of doing once again the thing that will fill it with the same value. Having a global in the main scope won't help much here, unless **I** am missing your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no good way to do this.

If you're using Dexie, it has [a `waitFor` function](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.waitFor()) which does let you keep a transaction open while waiting for another promise to resolve. But...

> Use with caution as it may put unnecessary CPU load on the browser. A separate task will keep the transaction alive by propagating dummy-requests on the transaction while the given promise is being executed.

If you don't use Dexie, you could implement the same thing yourself. Keep making requests while checking if your fetch promise is resolved yet.

It would be better to find some way to not have to keep the transaction active during the fetch. Like maybe store a flag in localStorage to prevent the 2nd call from doing anything? Or cancel the 1st fetch if a 2nd one starts before the 1st finishes? I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but usually there is some way to work around this limitation of IndexedDB.

Comment: localStorage is not an option for OP, they are in Workers, where Storages are inaccessible. One more CPU savvy way though would be to signal when a request is to be made using a BroadcastChannel and respond if the transaction is already open. But that's a big infrastructure to set up, and implies some weird async behavior with out of the hat timeouts...

Comment: I think the flag approach is 100% the way to go. They just need to store it in indexDB as well

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah I pretty much went with the approach describe here. That is a flag stored in the Db with a loop on the transaction waiting for the flag to clear. Was an interesting conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) to perform that operation.

This way all your page instances (and their Dedicated Workers) would be using the same SharedWorker which would be able to keep track of the transaction status, and thus be able to determine if it should make a new request or not.

It isn't supported in Safari though, but I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: I tried this initially but ran into issues that the code is part of a 3rd party library which gets loaded via URL.createObjectURL and a Blob of just an importScript from a 3rd party site. This meant that each page wasn't loading a single worker. It was in affect just a Worker, not SharedWorker.